# Viewing the queue contents of WSO2 Message broker

Tags: java, wso2, queue, message-queue, wso2-message-broker

Good morning,
I have a ambience wso2 MESSAGE BROKER where I shoot and consume messages inside a queue.
I would like to create a console (in addition to the MB) that allows me to consult what is inside the queue.

Is it possible?

tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, inside the MB you can see all the content of message (like the image below)

[image]

But if for some reason you still want to create your own message monitor, I advise you to take a look at the product administration API, you might be able to monitor it via API. Another possibility is to create a monitor via the same AMQP protocol and check all the queue.